# jQuery 1.8 ajax call returns null although post response has value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having problems with the return value of a jQuery ajax call.  I can debug the whole thing server side and I know everything is working correctly and the return value is properly being calculated.  I can look under the NET tab in FireBug and see that the response is:

{"d":false}

But when I test the value in the Success function of the ajax call, msg is NULL.  Why?

Here's the ajax call:

```
function GetStateCertifiable(areaID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../WebServices/AoP.asmx/GetStateCertifiable",
        data: '{"AreaID":"' + areaID + '"}',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);         // for debugging
            if (msg)
                $("#isCertified").slideDown("fast");
            else
                $("#isCertified").slideUp("fast");
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert("An error occured. \nStatus: " + result.status
                            + "\nStatus Text: " + result.statusText
                            + "\nError Result: " + result);
        },
        complete: function () {
        }
    });
};
```

Other, similarly structured client-side calls work fine.  This is a same-domain request.

Comment: does `alert(msg);` really outputs NULL and the inspector `{"d":false}`?

Comment: Off topic: use console.log() for debugging.

Comment: Well, had to answer this way (deleted it) - you never responded on my comment above. But WHEN you are not getting null, you should evaluate as I suggested.

Comment: Yes, alert(msg) displays NULL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that my web service (../WebServices/AoP.asmx/GetStateCertifiable) returned a bool and from the post response, I know that was properly sent back to the client.  Ajax, however, didn't like that.  Once I changed the web service to return the strings "true" or "false", everything worked.

Does jQuery ajax only work for strings or is there something I should have done to prepare the msg object to receive a bool?

Comment: It has to be valid JSON. boolean values in json are valid, and if you received invalid json, you wouldn't have gotten null. So, receiving null in this case makes no sense, unless your server really is sending null.

Comment: ...and you down voted me for what?  I explained in my original post that I didn't receive a null, I got {"d":false}.  However, the ajax call didn't seem to interpret that correctly.  I fixed it just as I explained above (which doesn't deserver an "answer not useful" vote.  I asked why this might be and you offered no useful information.

Comment: I find it to be unclear, not useless. The problem you are describing shouldn't be a problem at all with jQuery Ajax. More research is needed. This answer doesn't cover why you were getting null instead of an object.

Comment: Here's an example of jQuery's json parser (Hint: it uses JSON.parse) correctly parsing a boolean value: http://jsfiddle.net/y36nx4pq/

Comment: Thanks - since result resolves to NULL, $.parseJSON(result) also seems to resolve to NULL.

Comment: Can you provide a json string that does such? your example doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the name of the variable to something other than msg.  I think that might be a message box or something similar.  Try

```
function GetStateCertifiable(areaID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../WebServices/AoP.asmx/GetStateCertifiable",
        data: '{"AreaID":"' + areaID + '"}',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);         // for debugging
            if (result)
                $("#isCertified").slideDown("fast");
            else
                $("#isCertified").slideUp("fast");
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("An error occured. \nStatus: " + result.status
                            + "\nStatus Text: " + result.statusText
                            + "\nError Result: " + result);
        },
        complete: function () {
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Well, `msg` is in a local scope so that cannot be the reason.

Comment: Worth a try anyway - no luck.